Reading variable from a file into .htaccess causes an internal server error
What I'm Trying to Accomplish

I have more than 1,000 individual files in the format https://example.com/archives/<NNNNNN>.php where N is an integer.

I need to keep the existing structure as-is, though I can add to it. In this case, each page has a unique data-url-title="<url-friendly-title>".

I would like my .htaccess config to determine what file was read, use regex to extract the url-friendly-title, and rewrite the final URL to replace <NNNNNN>, in the format https://example.com/archives/url-friendly-title.php (I would then strip .php from it—but I didn't get that far).


What I Try to Do
# Enable rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Match the old archive URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/archives/([0-9]+)\.php$

# Check that the file exists
RewriteCond expr "-f '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/archives/%1.php'"

# Extract data-url-title from the file content
RewriteCond expr "file('%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/archives/%1.php') =~ /data-url-title=\"([^\"]+)\"/"

# Rewrite the URL to the new friendly URL
RewriteRule ^archives/([0-9]+)\.php$ /archives/%1.php [R=301,L]

What Happens
Any attempt to use this configuration causes my entire website to throw an internal server error with the log message RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters.

I don't think I have any spaces in my regex.

I've converted my .htaccess file to Unix endings.


I have looked at numerous answered questions, and they seem to indicate that, in Apache 2.4.x, it's possible to read a variable from an external file by using RewriteCond expr "<expression>":

Can .htaccess file read "variable" from external file?

I want to load text string from an external file into my .htaccess file


I can't get this to work. What more:

htaccess tester throws Unsupported TestString: expr for both RewriteCond expr statements.

.htaccess check specifically claims RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters for the second RewriteCond line.

I've tried postpending s to RewriteCond expr "file('%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/archives/%1.php') =~ /data-url-title=\"([^\"]+)\"/s" for newline matching, but the result is the same: internal server error in the browser; RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters in the logs.



The bad flag delimiters error appears to come from the double quotes, the escaping doesn't appear to do its intended job there. Can't find a combination that works either. You could either rewrite this to a PHP script, that then fetches this attribute value from the original file; or maybe have a script go over these files once, and have it rename them all according to that attribute value ...?

Just a side note: I fail to understand why one would want to implement such a complex setup. Why not simply use a database instead where the mapping from number to title is kept?

@CBroe I ended up doing something similar (I'll post my workaround when I have some free time), where the .htaccess detects pages with a specific pattern loaded from the specific directory, and then passes them to a script, which reads the value and remaps to a friendly URL on the fly. Not only does it all work fairly fast, but the logic still allows the legacy URLs to work, then remap to the new, friendly URL. In my opinion, there should be no reason why it would be impossible to do all of these conditional reads and redirects from .htaccess, but it is what it is.

@arkascha My main reason for wanting a dynamic solution is that the title can sometimes change, and that would mean that the friendly URL would also change. (Before you protest that the URL should be a permalink—I handle redirects from previous to current URLs separately; it's just how I wanted to set things up; I can't stand permalinks that don't match the current page.)

You miss understood what I said. I do understand the idea of an additional routing from number to title. I did something similar many years ago. What I don't understand is why you want to keep that mapping information in thousands of files instead of simply using a database. Those are made for such job.

@arkascha I'm afraid I don't have an answer that might satisfy you at this time. Perhaps my desire not to mess with databases?  Either way, I'm about to post the solution I found, so we can talk about that instead.

What you do is possible, but archaic. Using a database would be much more efficient, obviously, you'd just have to read all such files once for an import instead of for each and every request. But I understand that you hesitate to work into that field which appears to be new to you.

@arkascha Well, you'd read it once, but then you still need to scan the database and replace the title of an entry (and also its permalink) every time the entry title changes (which, by the way, does happen more than you'd expect). This doesn't make sense to me—if we're going to check the names every time, we might as well do it dynamically. This has nothing to do with me hesitating about anything.

Sure, if the title changes, then you need to change it, where ever you wrote it down, in a file or in a database field. Reading and writing from and to a database is much faster and more reliable than handling hundreds of files.

@arkascha Fair enough. I can try to implement this when I finally sit down to refactor the website; god knows, there's just way too much cruft to take care of there first. Cheers!

Well, because rewriting the page URL based on a variable within it, only by using .htaccess, seems unworkable . . . here's what I did:
/.htaccess
First things first, I check for the required pattern and pass it to the redirect.php handler script. However—here's the trick—I also pass the rewritten URL to the handler script to ensure that anyone using the old-style URL will still get a valid result.
# Enable rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect numeric IDs to friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^archives/(\d+)\.php$ /archives/redirect.php?id=$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Handle friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^archives/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /archives/redirect.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]

/archives/redirect.php
Here's where the fun begins. The comments in the code explain how the script works, but the point is that now:

Navigating to https://example.com/archives/friendly-name works correctly
Navigating to https://example.com/archives/000001.php still redirects to example.com/archives/friendly-name, for backwards-compatibility

<?php
// Iterate through all available `<NNNNNN>.php` files and check
// whether file contains the `data-url-title` attribute
function findMatchingFile($fileFormat, $isId = false) {
  $files = glob(__DIR__ . "/*.php");
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (basename($file) === 'redirect.php') continue;
    $content = file_get_contents($file); 
    if ($isId) {
      if (basename($file) === $fileFormat . '.php') {
        if (preg_match('/data-url-title="([a-z0-9-]+)"/', $content, $matches)) {
          return array($file, $matches[1]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (preg_match('/data-url-title="' . preg_quote($fileFormat, '/') . '"/', $content)) {
        return array($file, $fileFormat);
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Get input from query parameters
$input = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : (isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : '');

// Sanitize input
$input = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', '', strtolower($input)), '-');

// Find file matching input: if searchin by ID and matching file is found,
// redirect to archive URL; if searching by title, include matching fild
if (!empty($input)) {
  $result = findMatchingFile($input, isset($_GET['id']));
  if ($result) {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
      header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
      header("Location: /archives/" . urlencode($result[1]));
      exit();
    } else {
      include($result[0]);
      exit();
    }
  }
}

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo "404 Not Found";
?>

